# Table columns drag drop and add

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, drag

I'm using jQuery to drive my AJAX UI. I have a table of data, and I want to allow the user to reorder the columns in the table by dragging and dropping them. I have found few examples for the same.

But, I also want a function to add new column by dragging from a list of columns provided in the list and also to delete any columns from the current table.

Is there an existing solution?

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I am sorry, I can not share it. But is there any example available to fulfill the requirements. I have found one example [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Draggable-Table-Columns-Dragtable/) but its not having the add / delete